# How to get display Color Temperature via C#?

Tags: c#, colors, calibration

Does anyone have idea how to get or set display color temperature via C#?
I found Monitor Configuration Functions on Microsoft Dev Center, but it looks like for C++.
And there is no sample code of these functions.
Can anyone give me idea to call these functions in C#?

Thanks
Rex

Comment: If you link to the documentation then perhaps someone can work out how to call the specific function from C#

Comment: Use pinvoke to call winapi functions.  The pinvoke.net website is usually a fairly decent source for the [DllImport] declarations you need.  Not for this one however, it is a very obscure function and pretty worthless in practice.  Which also makes it unlikely an SO user will write the code for you.  A C++/CLI class library project lets you write the winapi code directly.

Comment: Sorry, that's my miss. Here is the link of functions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd692964(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hi Hans, Thank you. I will check Pinvoke.net.